# Entity Framework generic DbSet to List

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I'm try to bind generic `DbSet` to `Combobox` like this:

```
public static void BindComboboxByEntity(ComboBox combo, Type type, string displayMember, string valueMember, string orderBy)
{
    if (combo is ComboBox)
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            combo.ValueMember = valueMember;
            combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
            combo.DataSource = db.Set(type).OrderBy(orderBy);
        }
    }
```

Calling:

```
BindComboboxByEntity(MyCombo, typeof(MyEntity), "name", "id", "name");
```

But I know that I need to convert `IQueryable` to `List` for binding data to `Combobox`. How can I doing this?

Comment: added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are passing `Type type`, try this

```
var result = db.Set(type).OrderBy(orderByString).ToListAsync();
combo.DataSource = result.Result;
```

but my suggestion would be pass a generic class/entity

```
public static void BindComboboxByEntity<T>(ComboBox combo, string displayMember, string valueMember, string orderBy) where T : class
{
   if (combo is ComboBox)
        using (var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            combo.ValueMember = valueMember;
            combo.DisplayMember = displayMember;
            combo.DataSource = db.Set<T>().OrderBy(orderBy);
        }

}
```

then pass it as

```
BindComboboxByEntity<MyEntity>(MyCombo, "name", "id", "name");
```

Comment: Thank's! This is exactly what I needed!

Comment: @VladiSlav No worries, which part did you use?

Comment: Second part with passing generic entity.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the IQueryable still represent a "query" that has (in general) not been executed. You need to actually materialize the query (with a ToList() for instance)

```
combo.DataSource = db.Set(type).OrderBy(orderBy).ToList();
```

Note : You will need

`using System.Linq;`

Comment: If it were that simple ...I've got an error CS1061: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1061)
Although:
[link](https://imgs.info/i/kCxus)
[link](https://imgs.info/i/kCUSc)

Comment: Owww just noticed that your code is not Generic. 

Can you have something like `BindComboboxByEntity<T>` isntead of passing `Type type` as a parameter ? Then you can write something generic like dbSet<T>, which will get everything type correctly.

Comment: By the way, It would be nice to have a intermediate layer so that your combobox UI code does not directly contains code to the database. Usually, with EF it's done with a "repository pattern". It helps for this kind of trouble.